# POST Request UWP

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, uwp

I writing UWP app.

I need to send  POST request with json to server

Here is my code for downloading JSON and writing to value:

```
public async void AllOrders_down()
    {


        string url = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/index.php/?wc_orders=all_orders";

        var json = await FetchAsync(url);


        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

        OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);


    }
    public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
```

How I need to send POST request with this json to server?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example Post request that I have used in a UWP application.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://test.com/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));

    string endpoint = @"/api/testendpoint";

    try
    {
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourPocoHere), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //do something with json response here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Could not connect to server
        //Use more specific exception handling, this is just an example
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your code.

Back end dev saids that he see empty row, but data is not received.

Comment: Interesting. You received a 200 response from the endpoint you are trying to reach?

Comment: Yes.


I think I know where is problem.

I download json and write it to `var json` async.

When I set breakpoint I see that `json` value = null.

Comment: When I use your code null write to `content`. My row - `HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: If it's already Json, you don't need to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject. Just do new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

Comment: will try now and write you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VhwLEkcC

Look, here is my code, when I set breakpoint on this `HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

content is null

Comment: Response status is 200. I checked

Comment: Okay so you're only issue right now is building the request content correct?

Comment: Yes. Content is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127813/discussion-between-allen-rufolo-and-eugene).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `httpClient.PostAsync()`.

Comment: Okay, but how I need to write code, to take json from this `var json = await FetchAsync(url);` and send via POST request?

Comment: Something like this?

`using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
            }`

Comment: Better to call `var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);` for an `async/await` method.

Comment: hm. I write code like this, but nothing is posted

Here is my code

 `string url2 = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/post_from_local.php";
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url2, content);


            }`

Comment: What was `result` populated with? It should have some sort of result code.