# how to post string to URL in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uwp, httprequest

i want to post a string to an URL so that i can upload a file.
I did it in WPF project and i want to do it in UWP project.
this is my method in WPF:

```
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

  string url = "http://localhost/visualStudioUpload/upload1.php ";

  WebClient Client = new WebClient();
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            byte[] byteArray = Client.UploadFile(url, "POST", ofd.FileName);

           request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            //                  dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried with the `HttpClient` class?

Comment: The question is difficult to understand. What are you exactly asking? -1

Comment: i want to send a string to an url  so that i can upload a file to server
i did it in WPF project as i maintained and i want to do it in a UWP project but i failed to do so ..

Comment: @FlorianMoser i tried many solutions but nothing worked

Comment: Maybe show us what you have tried so far in UWP and show how you recieve the file in your endpoint.

Comment: i want to send a string to a php file containing the path of a file.
i tried this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489291/post-request-uwp
and this
http://kiewic.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync
and many others but nothing ..
i just need to send a string to an url
i work with a php file to upload a file and it needs a string (file.Path)

Comment: as a conclusion, can u help me make a program that can upload a file to server using c# UWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a file with the `HttpClient` (which replaces the `WebClient` in UWP)

Code:

```
private async Task<string> UploadImage(byte[] file, Uri url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(file));
        form.Add(content, "postname", "filename.jpg");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, form);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```