# How to send byte array to webservice ?? I am using xamarin forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, http-post, image-uploading

```
            -- xamarin forms code-- 
          public async void uploadimgAsync()
         {
          String pathofFile 
           ="/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.Lastappforcamera
            /files/Pictures/Sample/testone.jpg";

              using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pathofFile))
            {
                var bytes = default(byte[]);

                using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);

                    bytes = memstream.ToArray();
                }
              ax = bytes;

            }

            String URI = "xxxxxxxxx";

           await CrossFileUploader.Current.UploadFileAsync(URI, new 
            FileBytesItem("POST", ax, "testone.jpg"), new Dictionary<string, 
           string>()
                {
                   {"<HEADER KEY HERE>" , "<HEADER VALUE HERE>"}}
            );
           }

          --- web service method--- 

          [WebMethod]

       public String SaveDocumentPictureForXamarin(Byte[] 
       ImageByteArray,string ImageName)

        {
        string DocumentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload\\documents\\");

        if (!(Directory.Exists(DocumentPath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DocumentPath);
        }

         DocumentPath += ImageName; 

        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(DocumentPath, 
        FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        objfilestream.Write(ImageByteArray, 0, ImageByteArray.Length);

        objfilestream.Close();
        return "success";
         }
```

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Please help me to upload image as bytearray to web service. I couldn't get the code to upload. I tried httpclient, it shows web method error. I need to pass image name and imagebytearray. I am new to xamarin.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please take some more time to formulate you question properly; Its much easier to answer that way (for example use a descriptive header, format your code properly, ...) A very good guide on how to ask a good question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It also looks like this code would not compile, because `ax` is not defined before assigning to it. You may want to recompare the code you have posted vs the one you are using, and correct it. To upload files you may find this example helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679875/2259391